# How to embed "add node" form in a page and retain content-creation permissions?

Tags: 7

Question about adding "add node form" to page happened few times, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page

[Embed a "node add" form in a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/how-can-i-embed-a-node-add-form-in-a-page)

[render form in page--node--add--contenttype.tpl.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30919/render-form-in-page-node-add-contenttype-tpl-php)

[How do I embed a node creation form inside a view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91186/how-do-i-embed-a-node-creation-form-inside-a-view)

And it is also mentioned here: [Embed a node form with default values in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22139/embed-a-node-form-with-default-values-in-drupal-7)

Everyone gives this piece of code:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node_form = node_add('node_type');
```

So I used it that way:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items['content/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add: Content',
        'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_content_add_callback',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'weight' => 2,
    );
    return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_content_add_callback() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('MY_CONTENT_TYPE');
    return $form;
}
```

The intention was to show form to everyone, but not everyone should be able to create content by it. It should only encourage registering for gaining proper permissions. What I discovered after initial testing is that form added to page that way, is completely ignoring permissions. Even if anonymous user have no permission to create that kind of content - he can send this form, and content will be created. Maybe it is following only page access arguments or I don't know.

I'm writing this firstly to warn everyone who embed a form that way with the same intention, and secondly to ask, how can we embed form so it can be visible for everyone, but would still follow all Drupal permissions.

I know that I can add custom validation function, and it works, but I would like it to be following Drupal core permissions for content creation.

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you want that any user could have an ability to see and submit a form but on validation level you want to check if he/she has right permission?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is some line of code that we are missing, that would just add default validation. Otherwise it can be added by "if (!user_access('create TYPE content', $user))" in validation function. It just bothers me that we need to add this, and I'm trying to understand this behaviour.

Comment: I think there is no default user permission validation on node_add_form, but there is a `_node_add_access()` function which checks that a user has a proper permission. Also user permission on node creation is controlled on administration level. You can use _node_add_access() on your custom validation function.

Comment: You can also look at this that way - maybe we are adding this form to page wrongly? Maybe there is a better way, that doesn't make holes in security?

Comment: your MYMODULE_menu() is valid, but you need to render the form with render() function  on callback, I think. Add your own validation function with hook_form_alter and check user permission on that level..